# Immutable string in java

Tags: java, string

i have basic confusion .

```
String s2=new String("immutable");
System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));
s2.replace("able", "abled");
System.out.println(s2);
```

In first print statement it is printing **immutability** but it is immutable right? why so?
and 
in next printing statement it is not replaced> any answers welcome..

Comment: `Immutable` and `RValue` !

Comment: This tutorial will help you understand string immutability concept well. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/string-immutability-in-java/

Comment: what is that i didnt get? @RongNK

Comment: store the second replace statement's result in a variable and the changes will be reflected. s2.replace does create a new string but you are not storing that any where and the orignal object remains the same.

Comment: @Raj if you set `String s3 = s2.replace("able", "abled");` you will get the result. You have some below explanations.

Comment: In the second statemet the print statement returns the result of replace statement and thats why it gets printed. If you print the value of s2 after the first replace statement, you will see that the original value of s2 has not changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));
```

In above line, A new string returned and printed.

Because [String#replce()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

```
s2.replace("able", "abled");
```

It does the `replace`  operation but,not assigned the result back.So the original String remains the same.

You see the result if you assign the result.

like

```
String replacedString = s2.replace("able", "abled");
System.out.println(replacedString );
```

or

```
s2= s2.replace("able", "abled");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Update:

When you write line

```
System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));
```

That `s2.replace("able","ability")`  resolved and returned  String  passed to that function.

Comment: I'm not sure but are you sure that no new string is Generated?

Comment: -1! It does return a new String, just that its not assigned to anything.

Comment: even in the second line also i have not assigned to any variable

Answer (score 3):

The `replace(String,String)` method *returns* a new String. The second call to `replace()` returns the replacement but you don't assign it to anything, then when you print out the immutable `s2` again, you see the unchanged value.

Comment: I would add that String in Java is immutable and always creates a new String on changes.

Answer (score 2):

`String#replace` returns the resulting `String` without modifying the original (immutable) `String` value...

You will get the same result if you assign the result to another `String`, for example

```
String s2=new String("immutable");
String s3 = s2.replace("able","ability");
System.out.println(s3);
s2.replace("able", "abled");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Will give you the same out put...

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at line - 2:

```
System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));
```

This will print immutability, this is because

```
s2.replace("able","ability")
```

will return another string, which is fed like:

```
System.out.println(tempStr);
```

But in third statement,

```
s2.replace("able", "abled");
```

There is no assignment to another variable, so a string is returned but not assigned to any variable. Hence lost, but s2 remain as is.

Answer (score 0):

`Immutable objects are simply objects whose state (the object's data) cannot change after construction`

Your code `s2.replace("able","ability")`, it return a new String and nothing happen for `s2`.

And because `replace` function return a new String, so you can print the result by `System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));`

String is Immutable, but String have a lot of methods that you can use as `Rvalue`

**See also**:

- [Immutable objects](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29)
- [RValue](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5696)
- [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Answer (score 0):

`String s2=new String("immutable");`

1)When ever we create a String as above a new object is created.If we are trying to modify it, a new object is created with the content we are providing and our String s2 is not modified.

2)If we need the modified value in the s2 object then replace the above code as..

```
String s2=new String("immutable");//Creates a new object with content 'immutable'
System.out.println(s2.replace("able","ability"));//creates a new object with new content as //immutability
s2=s2.replace("able", "abled");//Here also it creates a new object,Since we are assigning it //to s2,s2 will be pointing to newly created object.
System.out.println(s2);//prints the s2 String value.
```